# Could not find class in rqt plugin

Tags: rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am developing rqt plugin. For this purpose, I initially created a python script called `my_module.py` and wrote rqt code into it. It was working fine.

Later on, I renamed the script file and provided a better name. I also renamed the class name inside it. However, now rqt is not able to load it. I even tried `catkin_make` and `sudo python setup.py install` commands on it. Below is the error:

```
RosPluginProvider.load(rqt_robot/robot Plugin): could not find class "robotPlugin" in module "<module 'rqt_robot.my_module' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_robot/my_module.pyc'>"
```

Any workaround, please? As always, thank you very much. Please note that I am using Python 2.7 in ROS Indigo on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS PC.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276178/could-not-find-class-in-rqt-plugin/) by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1744 on 2017-11-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I removed the old files and installed it again. More preciously, I did following steps:

1. Find out the path where this package is installed and go there `cd /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/`
2. remove the complete package by `rm -rf` command

---

Originally posted by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) with karma: 1744 on 2017-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0